# Is there any language where the "copula" is also identical with and function as an "auxiliary verb"?

Tags: linguistic-typology, copula, auxiliary-verbs

Are there languages where the "copula" is:

- invariant morphologically but may be phonologically conditioned (not inflected for any features like tense, number, etc. like English "is/was/were"),
- identical on all types of predication (verbal and non-verbal), and
- required on all sentences (not only on compound verbs like English "is/was/were" + verb + "-ing" or no zero copula like in Russian)? (EDIT: required even with finite verbs)

The "copula" in this case merely serves as a marker of predication.

(The word copula is quoted as it normally refers to non-verbal predication, and auxiliary verb to verbal predication.)

Comment: Turkish suffix _-dir_ and its seven other phonologically conditioned variants meets your first two criteria, but is not used when there is a finite verb present.

Comment: The Malay copulas 'ialah' and 'adalah' meet your first two criteria. Some speakers do use 'adalah' as if it were an auxiliary verb, especially before passive verbs that take clausal complements, but this is much frowned upon by prescriptivists because the copula isn't traditionally an auxiliary but a linker with no semantic content.

Comment: Thanks Colin Fine. I failed to mention it but I am looking for a particle copula, although an affix would be nice to explore as well.

Comment: One problem is that the copula is never absolutely required.  (eg English newspaper headline "Parliament at a standstill")

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: yeah in some languages, that's why I'm looking for a 'rare' language where it is required, so I can better understand it.

Comment: What if it doesn't exist? :-)

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: I have a suspicion/feeling it exists....7,000 languages to look at :D

Comment: To be efficient, any language should have a 'null verb'.  The logical choice is 'to be'.